# Where can I find one partner to listen to audiobooks together with me online?

Tags: reading

Most people listen to audiobooks on their own; afterwards they discuss with others.

However, I don't want to listen alone. The idea is that if two people are doing it **simultaneously**, it's easier to stick to it. For example, the learning partner will listen together with me for 20 minutes each day. My favorite is self-help books. Where can I find such a learning buddy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "**Come Here Often?**" Lifehack:

The Key to this success is being 'online' where the only thing you both share is a subject and the schedule.

**Online local classified advertising** is already being used for organizing groups finding common interests as well as for selling various items. Where I am located, there is Craigslist and others: (Kijiji, Backpage, Hoobly, Oodle.com, etc.)

Compose an ad to find another to share your interest and share your schedule. Your question here is a good start. Place it in the proper category.

Good Luck.